# How to prevent CycleGAN from generating crossing lines?

Tags: python, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I used CycleGAN to generate the images. During the model training phase, the input dataset (TrainA) and the ground truth (TrainB) are shown in the following figures (a) and (b). During the model testing phase, the model output is shown in figure (d).

My question is, there are no crossing lines in the training samples in Train B. Why are there crossing lines in the generated images (Test B)? How can I prevent CycleGAN from generating such crossing lines? What restrictions should I add to the loss function?

[image]

[image]

How to prevent CycleGAN from generating crossing lines? How can I prevent CycleGAN from generating such crossing lines? What restrictions should I add to the loss function?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.